# The Wordpress Contact Form 7 shortcode space before the id is causing 404 issues after the graphical editors truncate it

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-shortcode

I have encountered a strange hiccup with a Wordpress site that has a graphical editor requirement (Tatsu).  It is 97% mature, and of course there is now a problem.

Contact Form 7 was used to create a simple form capable of accepting a file attachment. With the classic editor the form embeds and functions without issue.  With Tatsu and a couple of other graphical editors the form works as embedded with their formatting and in all preview modes...until it is saved by the graphical editor.  Then we see the 404 error for the form.

If I use a traditional wordpress form, the embed is successful in both traditional editors and the graphical editors. What I have found is the Contact Form 7 (form) has a space in the shortcode whereas the traditional Wordpress forms do not.  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddtMQ.png).  I can't use the traditional Wordpress form for the file upload form because it requires an expensive paid version to accept the file upload and that PRO version isn't in the budget.

It appears as though the graphical editors are truncating the form's shortcode leading to the 404.

- I tried modifying the page's code and was moderately successful, until the required graphics-editor re-saves the page and chops off the form's shortcode. When the graphical editor sees the space in the shortcode, it appears to truncate the shortcode leading to the 404 error.  I can switch back to the classic editor and see the modified shortcode--the truncation.  With the classic editor I can correct it, but the formatting of the page is wonky until it is opened and re-saved by the graphical editor (Tatsu)...then the formatting is spot on but the form is broken.

-I tried the default wordpress form generator, but making the file upload happen required a costly PRO subscription.

- I think I'm searching for the wrong thing based on buzzword mismatches.  I've looked for how to alias a shortcode (I was thinking I could create a different form shortcode without a space and point to the Contact Form 7 shortcode with a space), but most information I find in that approach is lower-level concerning form fields.
- A more direct approach--I thought about modifying the shortcode, but can't find where the auto-generated form shortcodes are stored to attempt modification for the subject form's shortcode.
- A more aggressive approach--I tried a do_shortcode php approach, but it did not work.
- For grins I tried %20 in the shortcode reference, but met the same demise...404.  Suggestions to get past the hump are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with this in several combinations through the day.  I really dislike what some of these editors are doing to conform to their own style, but I understand.

The solution I found--there is another editor called PageSlayer.  Unlike the Classic editor, it allowed me to edit the html and save it precisely, preserving the style of the graphical interface.  This isn't a good solution because when anyone else goes into the graphical interface (Tatsu) to edit something they will lose the form...but it looks right and plays right this moment.

I have sent a request to support Contact Forms 7 to Tatsu.  Thanks for the time!